# SQL- Sorting with temp column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a work around with this type of sort in Microsoft SQL sever 2008?

Just want it to sort with my temp column.

`SELECT x AS TempTest FROM table1 WHERE TempTest IS NOT NULL`

Comment: `ORDER BY TempTest`?

Comment: `ORDER BY x ASC`

Comment: Have you tried with `order by`?

Answer (score 1):

I can never remember which versions support referencing aliased columns, but a surefire method is to use a derived table.

```
Select * From
(
    SELECT x AS TempTest FROM table1 
)MyTempTable 
WHERE TempTest IS NOT NULL
Order By TempTest
```

Answer (score 0):

All you're doing is aliasing an existing column, so just sort by the original column name. Alternatively, you could sort by the column ordinal position.

```
SELECT x AS TempTest FROM table1 WHERE x IS NOT NULL ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: I'm breaking this down into a simpler problem. So people won't get confused if I asked the bigger question.

Comment: Alternatively, you could sort by the alias.